# Angular 4 routing default page based on role

Tags: angular, authentication, angular2-routing

I have defined my routes as below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'teacher',
  component: 'TeacherComponent'
 },
{
  path: 'student',
  loadChildren: './components/student/student.module#StudentModule',
  canLoad: [AuthGuard]
},
{ path: '**',   redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

I want to route my default routing based on the loggedIn user role. If it's student, I want to default my path: '**' to be redirected to '/student'. Similarly for Teacher role I wanted it to default to '/teacher'.
How to implement this role based navigation by defaulting route to different urls based on the role?

Comment: First create a path that all users will load (blank page with loading icon) , this path(route) will always be loaded then once their role is loaded and checked inside the ngInit function, redirect them to the proper path.

Comment: By the time I load the roles, the routing is happening. How do I delay the routing until I get the roles?

Comment: That is you have to route to an intermediate route and there your application logic will come into play.

Comment: Thats why you send them to the blank page with the loading icon, which isn't behind any authGuards. You cannot delay routing

Comment: Got you. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am loading roles in app.component.ts and the respective role I am assigning to a variable in global file. But by the time I get this value in app.component, my blank page ngOnInit is getting fired, so I am not getting my role in the blank page. so is there any alternative to this apart from using ngAfterViewChecked?

Comment: Yes, you can actually delay routing. Use a route resolver. A route resolver will wait until data is resolved (retrieved and processed) before continuing on with the route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a route resolver.

Here is one of mine:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IMovie } from './movie';
import { MovieService } from './movie.service';

@Injectable()
export class MovieResolver implements Resolve<IMovie> {

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IMovie> {
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
        return this.movieService.getMovie(+id);
    }
}
```

This code will prevent the route from continuing until the movie is retrieved.

You could do something similar to retrieve your roles. Then instead of simply returning, you could use the data you retrieved to activate different routes depending on the user's role.

Comment: Use this in front of a "redirect" route as described in the comments to the question.

Comment: Does this need to be injected somewhere? Or does it work automagically by its own presence within the application?

Comment: Also, I find the example code to be "off track", it doesn't answer OP's question as directly as possible.

Comment: You don't need to inject it anywhere, but you do need to associated it with its route in the route configuration.

Comment: I don't believe that a requirement of SO is to write the OP's code for them. Rather, we provide an answer to their question with sample code. Using *my* existing sample code means it's syntax checked and working. I would not be able to write the specific code the OP needs without obtaining their source code (or at least much more information) so I can execute it to ensure it works. That's why including a stackblitz with a question can improve the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ path: "", component: LoginViewComponent, pathMatch: "full",canActivate:[AuthGuard] }

    @Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  role: string = "A";

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    const route = this.role === "A" ? "/home" : "/catalog";
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return true;
  }
}
```